# How to grab a specific error in a log with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to catch a specific error ("**Content is not allowed in prolog**") in the below log:

[image: Error-Log]

What I have done so far is the below, but I am not 100% sure that I am correct:

```
$regex = "\s:\s.+\.Content is not allowed in prolog.$"
```

Comment: Are you 50% sure then? What happens when you try to use the pattern stored in `regex` - does it work some of the time?

Comment: Do you want only first line or entry stack trace of the error?

Comment: Hi metablaster, I only need to error that I have marked with red: "Content is not allowed in prolog"

Answer (score 1):

You can go for `Select-String` to see if error existing in the log file.

```
Get-Content C:\Projects\logtext.txt | select-string " Content is not allowed in Prolog"
```

> org.xml.sax.saxparserexception: Content is not allowed in Prolog

Or

```
select-string -Path  C:\Projects\logtext.txt " Content is not allowed in Prolog"
```

> C:\Projects\logtext.txt:5:org.xml.sax.saxparserexception: Content is not allowed in Prolog

Comment: Hi Venkataraman, thank you for your solution. It is a little bit more complicated. I am actually trying to figure out how can I capture this specific error ("Content is not allowed in prolog"), every 5 minutes from a log, of course if it only exists. So, I don't want to always check the whole file.